# I thought I removed all bugs in my app but this one keeps popping up... Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I keep getting this error in my google log. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to decipher the problem here.
crash is:
Exception class
    java.lang.NumberFormatException
Source method
    FloatingPointParser.parseDouble()

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException:
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
at com.pipe.fittings.kevin.EqualSpreadOffset$1.onClick(EqualSpreadOffset.java:283)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4306)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanx all.

Comment: Something in your click handler is attempting to parse an invalid string. Could it be null? Blank? Do you not wrap parsing in a try/catch, or use a utility method that supplies a default on an exception? Push the "remove all bugs" button again.

Comment: +1 for concise, informative, to the point question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your stacktrace, it looks like you should examine the line:

```
com.pipe.fittings.kevin.EqualSpreadOffset$1.onClick(EqualSpreadOffset.java:283)
```

I'm guessing (like the others here) that your attempting to convert something that is not a number into a number and it is throwing an exception.

The **$1** indicates that the error is occurring the the first anonymous class within the class EqualSpreadOffset.  I will go out on a limb here and guess that it is probably a user entered field that is not properly validated before it is passed to your onClick method handler.

Comment: I just tested it. the app allows the use of a decimal point and if you just enter a decimal and no number it crashes... will have to take care of that. thanx all.

Answer (score 0):

explanation of NumberFormatException here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html

it looks like there is an attempt to parse a string into a Double and it is failing there.

Answer (score 0):

Use number parsing - you probablly want use String as number. Remember about `integer.parseint` and other helpers like this

Answer (score 0):

Try catching your exceptions and maybe this won't happen. A number format exception occurs when a string that is not a number is being attempted to be converted into a number.

For instance, if "kel" was trying to be turned into a number it would throw that exception because kel is not a number (obviously). Just look up try and catch and learn basic java and learn to read what your errors mean.